# Calculate days difference between every date column in Pandas dataframe at once

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, for-loop

I have a sample dataframe below `df`:

```
  Step 1 Step 2 Step 3 Step 4
0    1/1   2/13   3/23    4/7
1    1/6   2/27   3/26   4/11
2    1/9    3/2    4/1   4/18
```

I would like to get the days difference in days between each successive step all at once, and create a new column for each difference, like so:

```
  Step 1 Step 2 Step 3 Step 4  diff_btwn_1_2  diff_btwn_2_3  diff_btwn_3_4
0    1/1   2/13   3/23    4/7             43             38             15
1    1/6   2/27   3/26   4/11             52             27             16
2    1/9    3/2    4/1   4/18             52             30             17
```

Is there a way to do this efficiently in Python? I am running into some complications trying to loop through columns and dynamically name the variables based on the integer value associated with the step.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your dates `to_datetime`, which will given a mostly useless year value of 1900 (or assign your own year if you know what it should be). This then allows you to use `diff` to calculate the date difference between successive columns. Finally join the results back.

To keep your initial formatted dates, I'll work with a copy of your DataFrame that has `datetime` values.

Also, since you don't have year information you may need to be careful with the days depending upon whether you expect it to be a leap year or not.

```
import pandas as pd

dfdates = df.apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%m/%d')

# Get difference in days, drop first `NaN` diff. 
diffs = dfdates.diff(axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.dt.days).iloc[:, 1:]
# Rename columns
diffs.columns = 'diff_' + dfdates.columns[:-1] + '-' + diffs.columns

df = pd.concat([df, diffs], axis=1)
```

---

```
print(df)

  Step 1 Step 2 Step 3 Step 4  diff_Step 1-Step 2  diff_Step 2-Step 3  diff_Step 3-Step 4
0    1/1   2/13   3/23    4/7                  43                  38                  15
1    1/6   2/27   3/26   4/11                  52                  27                  16
2    1/9    3/2    4/1   4/18                  52                  30                  17
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. A couple of things, first my data originally does have dates with the year. Therefore, in my solution below, you will see I don't change the fields to datetimes (excluded the year in original post to save space). Secondly, there are NaT values in my original dataset, and solution posted by ALollz was causing unexpected behaviors (but works perfectly if there are no NaTs). I can't drop the NaT values from the original *process_df* because there would be almost no data in the later steps.

```
def create_days_diff_dataframe(data):
    '''Creates days difference column for every sequential milestone
    and adds to new dataframe'''
    days_diff_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(len(data.columns[:-1])):
        days_diff_btwn_milestones = (data.iloc[:, i + 1] - data.iloc[:, i]).dt.days
        days_diff_df['days_diff_' + data.columns[i] + ' - ' + data.columns[i + 1]] = days_diff_btwn_milestones
    
    return days_diff_df

days_diff_df = create_days_diff_dataframe(process_df)
```